# Dropzone Resize Function

Tags: resize, dropzone.js

I have implemented a dropzone page using http://www.dropzonejs.com/

I am having trouble with the resize functionality. My images are constantly cropped if they are of the wrong aspect ratio.

I am wondering two things:

1. Can i configure dropzone to fit (not stretch or crop) pics into the preview element.
2. Can I resize the previews after they are dropped (ie view the previews small, medium or large.

I have implemented 2 by adjusting the css, but im wondering if there is a better way using the dropzone code.

An example of 1 would be very helpful if anyone has one.
Thanks,
Matt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropzone.js + Client Side Image Resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533191/dropzone-js-client-side-image-resizing)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the preview seems to be croped only if you explicitly specify both options `thumbnailWidth` and `thumbnailHeight`. Otherwise, if your specify only one or no thumbnail dimension, the whole image is resized proportionally according to the specified options `thumbnailWidth` **or** `thumbnailHeight`.

Examples, with a *1200x800* image source:

```
// Resized preview (400x267)
var dp = new Dropzone(document.getElementById('dp'), {
    thumbnailWidth: 400,
    thumbnailHeight: null
}

// Resized preview (600x400)
var dp = new Dropzone(document.getElementById('dp'), {
    thumbnailWidth: null,
    thumbnailHeight: 400,
}

// Croped preview (400x400)
var dp = new Dropzone(document.getElementById('dp'), {
    thumbnailWidth: 400,
    thumbnailHeight: 400,
}
```

However, if you don't know the source image proportions and you need to make your preview fit in a sized div, then use the `resize` function of dropzone.js. It must return an object with multiple attributes, as it is describe in [the documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration). Here is an example to resize the preview according to your thumbnail dimensions:

```
var dp = new Dropzone(document.getElementById('myDropzone'), {

    // Your dropzone options here...

    thumbnailWidth: 400,
    thumbnailHeight: 400,
    resize: function(file) {
        var resizeInfo = {
            srcX: 0,
            srcY: 0,
            trgX: 0,
            trgY: 0,
            srcWidth: file.width,
            srcHeight: file.height,
            trgWidth: this.options.thumbnailWidth,
            trgHeight: this.options.thumbnailHeight
        };

        return resizeInfo;
    }
});
```

This will result in a stretch preview.
But of course, you can figure out `trgWidth` and `trgHeight` according to your source image dimensions, your sized div dimensions or whatever you want in order to make the preview looks like you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. To get thumbnails which are not cropped you need to do 2 things:

1. Specify a thumbnailWidth and a thumbnailHeight in the init options. If you want fixed height, pass null as the value for thumbnailWidth or vice versa if you want a fixed width.
2. Override the dropzone css as follows:

   .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image {
           width: auto !important;
           height: auto !important;
   }

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to specify a no-crop option in the config, but I managed to get it done by modifying dropzone.js in the following way, I hope it helps.

This modifications would preserve aspect ratio with a fixed height (you can change it to be width fixed).

**Line 1173** replace:

```
resizeInfo.trgWidth = _this.options.thumbnailWidth;
```

With this:

```
resizeInfo.trgWidth = img.width * (_this.options.thumbnailHeight / img.height);
```

And in **line 1182** replace:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, (_ref = resizeInfo.srcX) != null ? _ref : 0, (_ref1 = resizeInfo.srcY) != null ? _ref1 : 0, resizeInfo.srcWidth, resizeInfo.srcHeight, (_ref2 = resizeInfo.trgX) != null ? _ref2 : 0, (_ref3 = resizeInfo.trgY) != null ? _ref3 : 0, resizeInfo.trgWidth, resizeInfo.trgHeight);
```

With this:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, (_ref = resizeInfo.srcX) != null ? _ref : 0, (_ref1 = resizeInfo.srcY) != null ? _ref1 : 0, img.width, img.height, (_ref2 = resizeInfo.trgX) != null ? _ref2 : 0, (_ref3 = resizeInfo.trgY) != null ? _ref3 : 0, resizeInfo.trgWidth, resizeInfo.trgHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can set your options like this:

```
{
    thumbnailWidth: null,
    thumbnailHeight: null
}
```

And Dropzone will default on resizing your image.

Answer (score 0):

to get scaled thumbnails set one of thumbnailWidth or thumbnailHeight and the other one as null:

```
{
  thumbnailWidth: null,
  thumbnailHeight: "120"
}
```

and apply the following css:

```
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image {
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

max-width on img for responsive websites to scale the image on narrow screens.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a modification on @Gui-Don answer to keep the aspect ratio of the image.

```
thumbnailWidth: 400,
thumbnailHeight: 400,       
resize: function(file) {

        var thumbNHeight = this.options.thumbnailHeight;
        var thumbNWidth = this.options.thumbnailWidth;

        var ratio = 1;
        if (file.width > file.height) {
            ratio = (file.width / file.height);

            thumbNHeight = thumbNHeight / ratio;

        } else if (file.height > file.width) {

            ratio = (file.height / file.width);

            thumbNWidth = thumbNWidth / ratio;

        }

        var resizeInfo = {
            srcX: 0,
            srcY: 0,
            trgX: 0,
            trgY: 0,
            srcWidth: file.width,
            srcHeight: file.height,
            trgWidth: thumbNWidth,
            trgHeight: thumbNHeight
        };

        return resizeInfo;
}
```