# Dropzone.js: thumbnail of existing images are cropped

Tags: dropzone.js

I followed the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24545183/61018) to show already existing files on the dropzone area.

The problem is that the files appear cropped. See this image:

[image: left is existing, right is new dragged]

How should I go about fixing this? Has someone else seen this as well?

Comment: Do you have an example we can see somewhere? What does the CSS look like? I've never experienced this before.

Comment: Chris, let me whip something up. Thanks.

Comment: Ok my bad. I'll post an answer. Thanks for asking about a sample (I always forget to do this) because I often find the answer when I make one.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740117/dropzone-resize-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thumbnail you provide must be square.

Unlike what seems to be the behaviour of the newly dragged images, for added files, Dropzone will scale the picture and attempt to fit it in the image. That means if your image is wider than it is tall, you may see white space like the image shown in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, not always do we have images in one single form. The fix provided by Vladimir Mootin works well for all images.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by adding this css selector:

```
.dropzone{
  .dz-preview{
    .dz-image{
      img{
        height: 120px;
        width:120px;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    }
  }
}
```