# Dropzone.js resize image to fit the thumbnail size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

I'm trying to resize the image in the thumbnail to fix the box size. I've tried this :

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            maxFiles: 20,
            maxFilesize: 2,
            maxThumbnailFilesize: 20,
            acceptedFiles: 'image/*,.jpg,.png,.jpeg',
            thumbnailWidth:"250",
            thumbnailHeight:"250",
            init: function() {
                var dropzone = this, xhrs = [];
                $.each(uploadedImages, function (index, path) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('GET', path);
                    xhr.responseType = 'blob';//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        var file = new File([xhr.response], '', {'type': xhr.response.type});
                        //dropzone.addUploadedFile(file);
                        dropzone.emit("addedfile", file);
                        dropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, path);
                        dropzone.emit("complete", file);
                    };
                    xhrs.push(xhr);
                    xhr.send();
                });
                this.options.maxFiles = this.options.maxFiles - uploadedImages.count;
            }
        };
```

This is the original Image how it looks : 
http://files.parsetfss.com/12917a88-ac80-4e5e-a009-fc634161b79c/tfss-6c59b59f-8f57-4610-966e-31bbc203707b-samsung-galaxy-note-4-7290-002.jpg

And this is how it's displayed :
[image]

Also I've tried :

```
thumbnailWidth:"300",
thumbnailHeight:"300",
===
thumbnailWidth:"400",
thumbnailHeight:"400",
```

But nothing changed, `thumbnailWidth and thumbnailHeight` have no effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropzone.js + Client Side Image Resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533191/dropzone-js-client-side-image-resizing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can size a new image explicitly in javascript.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src =  'http://files.parsetfss.com/12917a88-ac80-4e5e-a009-fc634161b79c/tfss-6c59b59f-8f57-4610-966e-31bbc203707b-samsung-galaxy-note-4-7290-002.jpg';
img.height = 300;
img.width = 300;
```

`img` is now resized with proper dimensions.

Also, I just looked at the dropzone.js documentation and this method is probably of use. http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-resize

Comment: Thank's For this solution but I want to use `thumbnailWith  and thumbnailHeight...` of the library

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but if you call manually the resize function of the dropzone, the thumnails will be in the right dimensions:

```
var file = new File([xhr.response], '', {'type': xhr.response.type});
dropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(file,path);
dropzone.emit("addedfile", file);
dropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, path);
dropzone.emit("complete", file);
```

Comment: thanks, adding the method call "createThumbnailFromUrl" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was able to fix it by updating the `CSS` for the thumbnail that was generated.   You will need to put this in your CSS

```
.dz-image img{
    width: 130px;
    height:130px;
}
```

Explanation:
the problem is that the image is larger the the div and hiding the *rest* of the picture thus you end up with just a corner of it.

Answer (score 1):

After many tries, I found this and it worked fine for me.

```css
.dz-image img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```